# how to make a div vertically draggable without jqueryUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

Do I really need entire library (`jquery UI`) to make a div vertically draggable inside its parent?

I tried with attribute `draggable="true"` but it simply doesn't work.

```css
.wrap{text-align:center;}
.parent{display:inline-block; position:relative; padding:14px; background:lightblue; overflow:hidden; width:50%; height:54px;}
.title{position:absolute; left:0; top:0; background:gold; cursor:move; width:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='wrap'>
<div class='parent'>
<div class='title' id='title' draggable="true">DRAG ME UPandDOWN</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on [Draggable](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_draggable.asp) attribute in HTML. You probably missing `drop` and `drag` events.

Comment: I don't want to drop the div on any other parent.

Comment: How you sure the above code (your code) is not working?

Comment: try the snippet

Comment: Yes I tried, so asked to you, how you are saying it is not working. Because when you try to drag that yellow labeled text, it is dragging. Try the same thing with normal text. You won't see the same behavior.

Comment: no, it's not dragging, of course. You cannot move the text up and down